# Pass client id/information from a .NET client to a web socket service

Tags: c#, html, websocket

Is there a way to pass client information (such as an Id, username or other contextual information) from the client as part of making a websocket connection from a .net client(console,silverlight etc)?
This is how I'm making the connection to the socket service.

```
using (WebSocket socket = new WebSocket(@"ws://"+Environment.MachineName+":4502/commandserver"))
{
            socket.OnClose += socket_OnClose;
            socket.OnData += socket_OnData;
            socket.OnOpen += socket_OnOpen;
            socket.Open();
}
```

The ctor has an overload that accepts an "origin" and a "protocol", not sure if this can be used for passing any client information. If not is there an API call I can make to pass in the client information as part of making the connection?

EDIT: I'm using the [microsoft library](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info) for this and the sample service code adds the service object into a collection in it's ctor to keep track of client sessions. Hence I need a way to pass in some client data to the service object as part of the initial client connection so that I can use this to identify clients and send messages to specific clients (based on an ID for example) from the service.

Comment: The [WebSocket protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-09) recommends using cookies for user identification. Not sure if the library you're using supports this. What library is it?

Comment: It's the microsoft library from html labs:  http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/                       It doesn't seem to be well documented...

Comment: I've downloaded the library and took a look inside. It implements the latest draft (09) -- that's good! However, the WebSocket class doesn't seem to provide any method for setting cookies. So, unfortunately, I guess all you can do is provide the Id, username, etc. as query string parameters: `ws://localhost:4502/commandserver?id=1234&username=johndoe`

Comment: hmm...that sucks but looks like it's the only option. Thanks for your insights

Comment: Another solution is to send an initialization message (using standard socket communication) with the cookie data or other user info. In this case consider also any security concerns...